# Rsync not working well with VeraCrypt containers

Tags: rsync, veracrypt

I have a script that mounts a **Veracrypt** container in my external **HD**, **Rsync** files into it and then dismount the container.

Problem is that if I run it twice in a row, or some time later, for some reason all my files are copied again, like if the destination files were all modified after the first run.

Not sure if this is an issue with my **Rsync** line or **VeraCrypt** itself. Does **VeraCrypt** maybe change the files inside the container when you mount and dismount it and that's why Rsync thinks they're modified?

Here's an example of the script I'm using with dummy data:

```
# Dismount all existing containers
veracrypt -d

# Mount container
veracrypt -t --mount /media/${USER}/HD/vault /media/${USER}/veracrypt -p test --non-interactive

# Sync files
rsync -vhr --progress --delete ~/Downloads/WoW/ /media/${USER}/veracrypt/WoW/

# Dismount
veracrypt -d
```

Comment: Run it twice and each time check the modification times of the files on both occasions, compare them

Comment: Have a look at this perhaps it matters: https://sourceforge.net/p/veracrypt/discussion/features/thread/aba037cb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem ... I need to specify option`-t` (`-u` also helps in my case):

```
-u, --update                skip files that are newer on the receiver
-t, --times                 preserve modification times
```

Now it does not sync all files every time I run it.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that if you use a FAT file system in VeraCrypt and Rsync to/from another file system, some if not all data will still be copied over every time. All problems disappeared once I switched from FAT to Ext4 (the same FS my devices use that I copy to/from)